# tracking in opencv doesn't work when using FG_1

Tags: opencv

I'm using the tracking module in opencv on some videos. when I set fg=FG_0, it tracks moving objects in the video but not very accurately. When I set fg=FG_1, it doesn't track anything although FG_1 is supposed to be better than FG_0.
Any tips appreciated.
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/blobtrack.cpp?rev=1670

This is how i am running it:

blobtrack.exe fg=FG_1 bd=BD_CC bt=CC btpp=Kalman fgavi=fgvideo.avi input.avi

Comment: Could you present some code snippet(s)..?

Comment: Did a quick search but couldn't find anything about FG_1 in OpenCV documentation. Do you have some link to the doc or code snippets ?

Comment: We are not oracles. You need to provide some code or doc about your problem, like others said already..

Comment: I guess he is using the BlobTrack CvFGDetector (only thing where i ever read something like FG_0) ... but we seriously need more information to help out.

Comment: This is the code :
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/blobtrack.cpp?rev=1670